# My app force close in android OS version 6 up

Tags: android, forceclose

I created a project, then i build apk and instaling in android version 7 but cannot open or force close. But if instaled in android version 6 down my app normaly. Any body can help me? Thank you

Comment: "but cannot open or force close" what is happening then?

Comment: problem solved, there is button xml is not support with android with OS 6 or 7..